# Single Sign on ERROR on windows

Tags: single-sign-on

I am trying to set up single sign on with developer edition salesforce. I follwed the instruction with saying JDK1.8 required and set the path, JAVA_HOME e.t.c. After unzip and executed the start_up.bat. I got the following error. But the http://localhost:8443/admin page is letting me to proceed further.

What I have to do with fixing that error

> OpenIDM ready
>   Scheduled service "scheduler-service-group.salesforceDataSyncNow" invocation reported failure: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   org.forgerock.openidm.quartz.impl.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.impl.SystemObjectSetService.execute(SystemObjectSetService.java:280)
>           at org.forgerock.openidm.quartz.impl.SchedulerServiceJob.execute(SchedulerServiceJob.java:127)
>           at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
>           at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.impl.SystemObjectSetService.liveSync(SystemObjectSetService.java:327)
>           at org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.impl.SystemObjectSetService.execute(SystemObjectSetService.java:273)
>           ... 3 more

Comment: Hi Ganesh, and welcome to SFSE! I just wanted to take a moment to mention that your question, as it stands, is likely to be closed. Please take a look at [ask] for more information on how to use SFSE, and do feel free to [edit] your question so that it's more on-topic. It's also possible that this question might be better suited on [so], since it appears to be a generic Java question that happens to have salesforce.com involved tangentially.